Injecting noise model into quantum simulator
I am trying to inject Noise model in to simulator and want to test whether noise actually affects the quantum computation of the circuit or not? Below is a sample code tested on qiskit ==1.0.
import numpy as np
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit, QuantumRegister
from qiskit.circuit.library import UCRYGate
from qiskit.transpiler.preset_passmanagers import generate_preset_pass_manager
from qiskit_ibm_runtime.fake_provider import  FakeKolkata
from qiskit_ibm_runtime.fake_provider import FakeBrisbane, FakeSherbrooke
from qiskit_aer import Aer
from qiskit_aer.noise import NoiseModel
import math
import pdb
num_qubits = 3
data = np.array([
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
    [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
])
angles = [np.pi / 4, np.pi / 2, 3 * np.pi / 4, np.pi]
controls = [0, 1]
target = [2]

qr1 = QuantumRegister(num_qubits, name= 'q')
qc1 = QuantumCircuit(qr1)
qc1.append(UCRYGate(angles), controls + target)
qc1.append(UCRYGate(angles), controls + target)

qr2 = QuantumRegister(num_qubits, name='q')
qc2= QuantumCircuit(qr2)

qc2.unitary(data, qr2, label= 'u')

qc1 = qc1.compose(qc2, list(range(0, num_qubits)))
qc1 = qc1.decompose()  # Decomposing the quantum circuit
print(qc1.draw())

qc1.measure_all()


# print(qc1.draw())
shots_used = 10000
print("Circuit depth: ", qc2.depth())
print("Circuit gate counts:", qc2.count_ops())

# backend_fake = FakeKolkata()
backend_fake = FakeSherbrooke()
noise_model = NoiseModel.from_backend(backend_fake)
print(noise_model)
coupling_map = backend_fake.coupling_map
backend = Aer.get_backend('qasm_simulator', noise_model = noise_model, coupling_map= coupling_map)

pm = generate_preset_pass_manager(backend=backend, optimization_level=3)
qc_optimized = pm.run(qc1)
# pdb.set_trace()
print("Optimzied circuit depth: ", qc_optimized.depth())
print("Optimized gate counts:", qc_optimized.count_ops())
# pdb.set_trace()
print(qc_optimized.draw())

job = backend.run(qc_optimized, noise_model = noise_model, shots = shots_used)
result = job.result()
counts = result.get_counts(qc_optimized)

Below is the the noise model content and the printed quantum circuit. I am really not sure how all this noise related things work and how to even test it correctly. What i feel is that if the circuit contains similar gates as in noise model, then it should affect otherwise not, but I am not sure about this. Also, my circuit contains so many U3 and U gates. I am really not sure whether the noise model will affect them any how? Please help in correcting my code.
NoiseModel:
Basis gates: ['delay', 'ecr', 'for_loop', 'id', 'if_else', 'measure', 'reset', 'rz', 'switch_case', 'sx', 'x']
Instructions with noise: ['reset', 'id', 'x', 'ecr', 'sx', 'measure']
Qubits with noise: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121, 122, 123, 124, 125, 126]
Specific qubit errors: [('reset', (0,)), ('reset', (1,)), ('reset', (2,)), ('reset', (3,)), ('reset', (4,)), ('reset', (5,)), ('reset', (6,)), ('reset', (7,)), ('reset', (8,)), ('reset', (9,)), ('reset', (10,)), ('reset', (11,)), ('reset', (12,)), ('reset', (13,)), ('reset', (14,)), ('reset', (15,)), ('reset', (16,)), ('reset', (17,)), ('reset', (18,)), ('reset', (19,)), ('reset', (20,)), ('reset', (21,)), ('reset', (22,)), ('reset', (23,)), ('reset', (24,)), ('reset', (25,)), ('reset', (26,)), ('reset', (27,)), ('reset', (28,)), ('reset', (29,)), ('reset', (30,)), ('reset', (31,)), ('reset', (32,)), ('reset', (33,)), ('reset', (34,)), ('reset', (35,)), ('reset', (36,)), ('reset', (37,)), ('reset', (38,)), ('reset', (39,)), ('reset', (40,)), ('reset', (41,)), ('reset', (42,)), ('reset', (43,)), ('reset', (44,)), ('reset', (45,)), ('reset', (46,)), ('reset', (47,)), ('reset', (48,)), ('reset', (49,)), ('reset', (50,)), ('reset', (51,)), ('reset', (52,)), ('reset', (53,)), ('reset', (54,)), ('reset', (55,)), ('reset', (56,)), ('reset', (57,)), ('reset', (58,)), ('reset', (59,)), ('reset', (60,)), ('reset', (61,)), ('reset', (62,)), ('reset', (63,)), ('reset', (64,)), ('reset', (65,)), ('reset', (66,)), ('reset', (67,)), ('reset', (68,)), ('reset', (69,)), ('reset', (70,)), ('reset', (71,)), ('reset', (72,)), ('reset', (73,)), ('reset', (74,)), ('reset', (75,)), ('reset', (76,)), ('reset', (77,)), ('reset', (78,)), ('reset', (79,)), ('reset', (80,)), ('reset', (81,)), ('reset', (82,)), ('reset', (83,)), ('reset', (84,)), ('reset', (85,)), ('reset', (86,)), ('reset', (87,)), ('reset', (88,)), ('reset', (89,)), ('reset', (90,)), ('reset', (91,)), ('reset', (92,)), ('reset', (93,)), ('reset', (94,)), ('reset', (95,)), ('reset', (96,)), ('reset', (97,)), ('reset', (98,)), ('reset', (99,)), ('reset', (100,)), ('reset', (101,)), ('reset', (102,)), ('reset', (103,)), ('reset', (104,)), ('reset', (105,)), ('reset', (106,)), ('reset', (107,)), ('reset', (108,)), ('reset', (109,)), ('reset', (110,)), ('reset', (111,)), ('reset', (112,)), ('reset', (113,)), ('reset', (114,)), ('reset', (115,)), ('reset', (116,)), ('reset', (117,)), ('reset', (118,)), ('reset', (119,)), ('reset', (120,)), ('reset', (121,)), ('reset', (122,)), ('reset', (123,)), ('reset', (124,)), ('reset', (125,)), ('reset', (126,)), ('id', (0,)), ('id', (1,)), ('id', (2,)), ('id', (3,)), ('id', (4,)), ('id', (5,)), ('id', (6,)), ('id', (7,)), ('id', (8,)), ('id', (9,)), ('id', (10,)), ('id', (11,)), ('id', (12,)), ('id', (13,)), ('id', (14,)), ('id', (15,)), ('id', (16,)), ('id', (17,)), ('id', (18,)), ('id', (19,)), ('id', (20,)), ('id', (21,)), ('id', (22,)), ('id', (23,)), ('id', (24,)), ('id', (25,)), ('id', (26,)), ('id', (27,)), ('id', (28,)), ('id', (29,)), ('id', (30,)), ('id', (31,)), ('id', (32,)), ('id', (33,)), ('id', (34,)), ('id', (35,)), ('id', (36,)), ('id', (37,)), ('id', (38,)), ('id', (39,)), ('id', (40,)), ('id', (41,)), ('id', (42,)), ('id', (43,)), ('id', (44,)), ('id', (45,)), ('id', (46,)), ('id', (47,)), ('id', (48,)), ('id', (49,)), ('id', (50,)), ('id', (51,)), ('id', (52,)), ('id', (53,)), ('id', (54,)), ('id', (55,)), ('id', (56,)), ('id', (57,)), ('id', (58,)), ('id', (59,)), ('id', (60,)), ('id', (61,)), ('id', (62,)), ('id', (63,)), ('id', (64,)), ('id', (65,)), ('id', (66,)), ('id', (67,)), ('id', (68,)), ('id', (69,)), ('id', (70,)), ('id', (71,)), ('id', (72,)), ('id', (73,)), ('id', (74,)), ('id', (75,)), ('id', (76,)), ('id', (77,)), ('id', (78,)), ('id', (79,)), ('id', (80,)), ('id', (81,)), ('id', (82,)), ('id', (83,)), ('id', (84,)), ('id', (85,)), ('id', (86,)), ('id', (87,)), ('id', (88,)), ('id', (89,)), ('id', (90,)), ('id', (91,)), ('id', (92,)), ('id', (93,)), ('id', (94,)), ('id', (95,)), ('id', (96,)), ('id', (97,)), ('id', (98,)), ('id', (99,)), ('id', (100,)), ('id', (101,)), ('id', (102,)), ('id', (103,)), ('id', (104,)), ('id', (105,)), ('id', (106,)), ('id', (107,)), ('id', (108,)), ('id', (109,)), ('id', (110,)), ('id', (111,)), ('id', (112,)), ('id', (113,)), ('id', (114,)), ('id', (115,)), ('id', (116,)), ('id', (117,)), ('id', (118,)), ('id', (119,)), ('id', (120,)), ('id', (121,)), ('id', (122,)), ('id', (123,)), ('id', (124,)), ('id', (125,)), ('id', (126,)), ('ecr', (1, 0)), ('ecr', (1, 2)), ('ecr', (3, 2)), ('ecr', (4, 3)), ('ecr', (4, 15)), ('ecr', (5, 4)), ('ecr', (6, 5)), ('ecr', (7, 6)), ('ecr', (8, 7)), ('ecr', (8, 9)), ('ecr', (10, 9)), ('ecr', (10, 11)), ('ecr', (11, 12)), ('ecr', (12, 13)), ('ecr', (14, 0)), ('ecr', (14, 18)), ('ecr', (16, 8)), ('ecr', (17, 12)), ('ecr', (17, 30)), ('ecr', (18, 19)), ('ecr', (19, 20)), ('ecr', (20, 33)), ('ecr', (21, 20)), ('ecr', (21, 22)), ('ecr', (22, 15)), ('ecr', (23, 22)), ('ecr', (23, 24)), ('ecr', (25, 24)), ('ecr', (26, 16)), ('ecr', (26, 25)), ('ecr', (26, 27)), ('ecr', (28, 27)), ('ecr', (29, 28)), ('ecr', (29, 30)), ('ecr', (31, 30)), ('ecr', (31, 32)), ('ecr', (32, 36)), ('ecr', (33, 39)), ('ecr', (34, 24)), ('ecr', (35, 28)), ('ecr', (35, 47)), ('ecr', (36, 51)), ('ecr', (37, 38)), ('ecr', (38, 39)), ('ecr', (40, 39)), ('ecr', (41, 40)), ('ecr', (41, 53)), ('ecr', (42, 41)), ('ecr', (43, 34)), ('ecr', (43, 42)), ('ecr', (43, 44)), ('ecr', (45, 44)), ('ecr', (45, 46)), ('ecr', (47, 46)), ('ecr', (47, 48)), ('ecr', (49, 48)), ('ecr', (49, 50)), ('ecr', (50, 51)), ('ecr', (52, 37)), ('ecr', (53, 60)), ('ecr', (54, 45)), ('ecr', (55, 49)), ('ecr', (56, 52)), ('ecr', (56, 57)), ('ecr', (57, 58)), ('ecr', (59, 58)), ('ecr', (59, 60)), ('ecr', (61, 60)), ('ecr', (61, 62)), ('ecr', (63, 62)), ('ecr', (63, 64)), ('ecr', (64, 54)), ('ecr', (64, 65)), ('ecr', (66, 65)), ('ecr', (67, 66)), ('ecr', (68, 55)), ('ecr', (68, 67)), ('ecr', (69, 68)), ('ecr', (69, 70)), ('ecr', (71, 58)), ('ecr', (71, 77)), ('ecr', (72, 62)), ('ecr', (73, 66)), ('ecr', (73, 85)), ('ecr', (74, 70)), ('ecr', (75, 76)), ('ecr', (77, 76)), ('ecr', (78, 77)), ('ecr', (78, 79)), ('ecr', (79, 91)), ('ecr', (80, 79)), ('ecr', (80, 81)), ('ecr', (81, 72)), ('ecr', (81, 82)), ('ecr', (82, 83)), ('ecr', (84, 83)), ('ecr', (85, 84)), ('ecr', (86, 85)), ('ecr', (86, 87)), ('ecr', (87, 88)), ('ecr', (89, 74)), ('ecr', (89, 88)), ('ecr', (90, 75)), ('ecr', (90, 94)), ('ecr', (92, 83)), ('ecr', (92, 102)), ('ecr', (93, 87)), ('ecr', (93, 106)), ('ecr', (95, 94)), ('ecr', (95, 96)), ('ecr', (97, 96)), ('ecr', (97, 98)), ('ecr', (98, 91)), ('ecr', (99, 98)), ('ecr', (99, 100)), ('ecr', (101, 100)), ('ecr', (101, 102)), ('ecr', (102, 103)), ('ecr', (104, 103)), ('ecr', (105, 104)), ('ecr', (106, 105)), ('ecr', (107, 106)), ('ecr', (107, 108)), ('ecr', (109, 96)), ('ecr', (110, 100)), ('ecr', (110, 118)), ('ecr', (111, 104)), ('ecr', (112, 108)), ('ecr', (112, 126)), ('ecr', (113, 114)), ('ecr', (114, 109)), ('ecr', (114, 115)), ('ecr', (116, 115)), ('ecr', (117, 116)), ('ecr', (117, 118)), ('ecr', (119, 118)), ('ecr', (119, 120)), ('ecr', (120, 121)), ('ecr', (121, 122)), ('ecr', (122, 111)), ('ecr', (123, 122)), ('ecr', (124, 123)), ('ecr', (125, 124)), ('ecr', (126, 125)), ('x', (0,)), ('x', (1,)), ('x', (2,)), ('x', (3,)), ('x', (4,)), ('x', (5,)), ('x', (6,)), ('x', (7,)), ('x', (8,)), ('x', (9,)), ('x', (10,)), ('x', (11,)), ('x', (12,)), ('x', (13,)), ('x', (14,)), ('x', (15,)), ('x', (16,)), ('x', (17,)), ('x', (18,)), ('x', (19,)), ('x', (20,)), ('x', (21,)), ('x', (22,)), ('x', (23,)), ('x', (24,)), ('x', (25,)), ('x', (26,)), ('x', (27,)), ('x', (28,)), ('x', (29,)), ('x', (30,)), ('x', (31,)), ('x', (32,)), ('x', (33,)), ('x', (34,)), ('x', (35,)), ('x', (36,)), ('x', (37,)), ('x', (38,)), ('x', (39,)), ('x', (40,)), ('x', (41,)), ('x', (42,)), ('x', (43,)), ('x', (44,)), ('x', (45,)), ('x', (46,)), ('x', (47,)), ('x', (48,)), ('x', (49,)), ('x', (50,)), ('x', (51,)), ('x', (52,)), ('x', (53,)), ('x', (54,)), ('x', (55,)), ('x', (56,)), ('x', (57,)), ('x', (58,)), ('x', (59,)), ('x', (60,)), ('x', (61,)), ('x', (62,)), ('x', (63,)), ('x', (64,)), ('x', (65,)), ('x', (66,)), ('x', (67,)), ('x', (68,)), ('x', (69,)), ('x', (70,)), ('x', (71,)), ('x', (72,)), ('x', (73,)), ('x', (74,)), ('x', (75,)), ('x', (76,)), ('x', (77,)), ('x', (78,)), ('x', (79,)), ('x', (80,)), ('x', (81,)), ('x', (82,)), ('x', (83,)), ('x', (84,)), ('x', (85,)), ('x', (86,)), ('x', (87,)), ('x', (88,)), ('x', (89,)), ('x', (90,)), ('x', (91,)), ('x', (92,)), ('x', (93,)), ('x', (94,)), ('x', (95,)), ('x', (96,)), ('x', (97,)), ('x', (98,)), ('x', (99,)), ('x', (100,)), ('x', (101,)), ('x', (102,)), ('x', (103,)), ('x', (104,)), ('x', (105,)), ('x', (106,)), ('x', (107,)), ('x', (108,)), ('x', (109,)), ('x', (110,)), ('x', (111,)), ('x', (112,)), ('x', (113,)), ('x', (114,)), ('x', (115,)), ('x', (116,)), ('x', (117,)), ('x', (118,)), ('x', (119,)), ('x', (120,)), ('x', (121,)), ('x', (122,)), ('x', (123,)), ('x', (124,)), ('x', (125,)), ('x', (126,)), ('sx', (0,)), ('sx', (1,)), ('sx', (2,)), ('sx', (3,)), ('sx', (4,)), ('sx', (5,)), ('sx', (6,)), ('sx', (7,)), ('sx', (8,)), ('sx', (9,)), ('sx', (10,)), ('sx', (11,)), ('sx', (12,)), ('sx', (13,)), ('sx', (14,)), ('sx', (15,)), ('sx', (16,)), ('sx', (17,)), ('sx', (18,)), ('sx', (19,)), ('sx', (20,)), ('sx', (21,)), ('sx', (22,)), ('sx', (23,)), ('sx', (24,)), ('sx', (25,)), ('sx', (26,)), ('sx', (27,)), ('sx', (28,)), ('sx', (29,)), ('sx', (30,)), ('sx', (31,)), ('sx', (32,)), ('sx', (33,)), ('sx', (34,)), ('sx', (35,)), ('sx', (36,)), ('sx', (37,)), ('sx', (38,)), ('sx', (39,)), ('sx', (40,)), ('sx', (41,)), ('sx', (42,)), ('sx', (43,)), ('sx', (44,)), ('sx', (45,)), ('sx', (46,)), ('sx', (47,)), ('sx', (48,)), ('sx', (49,)), ('sx', (50,)), ('sx', (51,)), ('sx', (52,)), ('sx', (53,)), ('sx', (54,)), ('sx', (55,)), ('sx', (56,)), ('sx', (57,)), ('sx', (58,)), ('sx', (59,)), ('sx', (60,)), ('sx', (61,)), ('sx', (62,)), ('sx', (63,)), ('sx', (64,)), ('sx', (65,)), ('sx', (66,)), ('sx', (67,)), ('sx', (68,)), ('sx', (69,)), ('sx', (70,)), ('sx', (71,)), ('sx', (72,)), ('sx', (73,)), ('sx', (74,)), ('sx', (75,)), ('sx', (76,)), ('sx', (77,)), ('sx', (78,)), ('sx', (79,)), ('sx', (80,)), ('sx', (81,)), ('sx', (82,)), ('sx', (83,)), ('sx', (84,)), ('sx', (85,)), ('sx', (86,)), ('sx', (87,)), ('sx', (88,)), ('sx', (89,)), ('sx', (90,)), ('sx', (91,)), ('sx', (92,)), ('sx', (93,)), ('sx', (94,)), ('sx', (95,)), ('sx', (96,)), ('sx', (97,)), ('sx', (98,)), ('sx', (99,)), ('sx', (100,)), ('sx', (101,)), ('sx', (102,)), ('sx', (103,)), ('sx', (104,)), ('sx', (105,)), ('sx', (106,)), ('sx', (107,)), ('sx', (108,)), ('sx', (109,)), ('sx', (110,)), ('sx', (111,)), ('sx', (112,)), ('sx', (113,)), ('sx', (114,)), ('sx', (115,)), ('sx', (116,)), ('sx', (117,)), ('sx', (118,)), ('sx', (119,)), ('sx', (120,)), ('sx', (121,)), ('sx', (122,)), ('sx', (123,)), ('sx', (124,)), ('sx', (125,)), ('sx', (126,)), ('measure', (0,)), ('measure', (1,)), ('measure', (2,)), ('measure', (3,)), ('measure', (4,)), ('measure', (5,)), ('measure', (6,)), ('measure', (7,)), ('measure', (8,)), ('measure', (9,)), ('measure', (10,)), ('measure', (11,)), ('measure', (12,)), ('measure', (13,)), ('measure', (14,)), ('measure', (15,)), ('measure', (16,)), ('measure', (17,)), ('measure', (18,)), ('measure', (19,)), ('measure', (20,)), ('measure', (21,)), ('measure', (22,)), ('measure', (23,)), ('measure', (24,)), ('measure', (25,)), ('measure', (26,)), ('measure', (27,)), ('measure', (28,)), ('measure', (29,)), ('measure', (30,)), ('measure', (31,)), ('measure', (32,)), ('measure', (33,)), ('measure', (34,)), ('measure', (35,)), ('measure', (36,)), ('measure', (37,)), ('measure', (38,)), ('measure', (39,)), ('measure', (40,)), ('measure', (41,)), ('measure', (42,)), ('measure', (43,)), ('measure', (44,)), ('measure', (45,)), ('measure', (46,)), ('measure', (47,)), ('measure', (48,)), ('measure', (49,)), ('measure', (50,)), ('measure', (51,)), ('measure', (52,)), ('measure', (53,)), ('measure', (54,)), ('measure', (55,)), ('measure', (56,)), ('measure', (57,)), ('measure', (58,)), ('measure', (59,)), ('measure', (60,)), ('measure', (61,)), ('measure', (62,)), ('measure', (63,)), ('measure', (64,)), ('measure', (65,)), ('measure', (66,)), ('measure', (67,)), ('measure', (68,)), ('measure', (69,)), ('measure', (70,)), ('measure', (71,)), ('measure', (72,)), ('measure', (73,)), ('measure', (74,)), ('measure', (75,)), ('measure', (76,)), ('measure', (77,)), ('measure', (78,)), ('measure', (79,)), ('measure', (80,)), ('measure', (81,)), ('measure', (82,)), ('measure', (83,)), ('measure', (84,)), ('measure', (85,)), ('measure', (86,)), ('measure', (87,)), ('measure', (88,)), ('measure', (89,)), ('measure', (90,)), ('measure', (91,)), ('measure', (92,)), ('measure', (93,)), ('measure', (94,)), ('measure', (95,)), ('measure', (96,)), ('measure', (97,)), ('measure', (98,)), ('measure', (99,)), ('measure', (100,)), ('measure', (101,)), ('measure', (102,)), ('measure', (103,)), ('measure', (104,)), ('measure', (105,)), ('measure', (106,)), ('measure', (107,)), ('measure', (108,)), ('measure', (109,)), ('measure', (110,)), ('measure', (111,)), ('measure', (112,)), ('measure', (113,)), ('measure', (114,)), ('measure', (115,)), ('measure', (116,)), ('measure', (117,)), ('measure', (118,)), ('measure', (119,)), ('measure', (120,)), ('measure', (121,)), ('measure', (122,)), ('measure', (123,)), ('measure', (124,)), ('measure', (125,)), ('measure', (126,))] 

It took me a lot of time to understand this concept, but I am very sure this is the correct way to do it. This code works with the latest version of qiskit==1.0
import numpy as np
import pdb
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit, QuantumRegister
from qiskit.circuit.library import UCRYGate
from qiskit.transpiler.preset_passmanagers import generate_preset_pass_manager

from qiskit_ibm_runtime import QiskitRuntimeService, SamplerV2 as Sampler  # Not sue what is the Need for this
from qiskit_aer import Aer
from qiskit_aer import AerSimulator

from qiskit_ibm_runtime.fake_provider import FakeKolkataV2
from qiskit_ibm_runtime.fake_provider import FakeBrisbane, FakeSherbrooke
from qiskit_aer.noise import NoiseModel
import math

backend = FakeKolkataV2()
noise_model = NoiseModel.from_backend(backend)
coupling_map = backend.coupling_map


num_qubits = 3
data = np.array([
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
    [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
])
angles = [np.pi / 4, np.pi / 2, 3 * np.pi / 4, np.pi]
controls = [0, 1]
target = [2]

qr1 = QuantumRegister(num_qubits, name= 'q')
qc1 = QuantumCircuit(qr1)
qc1.append(UCRYGate(angles), controls + target)
qc1.append(UCRYGate(angles), controls + target)

qr2 = QuantumRegister(num_qubits, name='q')
qc2= QuantumCircuit(qr2)

qc2.unitary(data, qr2, label= 'u')

qc = qc1.compose(qc2, list(range(0, num_qubits)))
qc.measure_all()



simulator = AerSimulator(noise_model = noise_model, coupling_map = coupling_map)

pm = generate_preset_pass_manager(backend=backend, optimization_level = 1)
circuit_opt = pm.run(qc)
print(circuit_opt.draw())

job = simulator.run(circuit_opt, noise_model = noise_model, shots = 1000)
result = job.result()
counts = result.get_counts(circuit_opt)
print(counts)

